# How to build html using Groovy MarkupBuilder?

Tags: groovy

I try a simple groovy script.

```
def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(out)
builder.ul{
     li {
        a( href : "href.html" ) { 
           span(class:"class") 
           "Content" 
           }
     }
 }
```

output:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='href.html'>
        <span class='class' />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

my Question is why "Content" is missing?
How could i fix this.

Groovy version 1.7.10

**EDIT:**

what i wanted is ("Content" outside `<span>`)

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='href.html'>
        <span class='class' />
        Content
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

With latest edit to question, answer should be:

```
builder.ul{
    li {
       a( href : "href.html" ) { 
           span class:"class"
           mkp.yield "Content"
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. `mkp.yield` throw a nullpoint exception. i changed to `builder.mkp.yield` works fine.

Comment: more refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482929/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-using-html-builder-with-mixed-content-in-groovy-1

Comment: That should not be a problem `mkp` is available in MarkupBuilder by default. [API from 1.7.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/1.7.2/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.java) says the same thing as the [latest API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html). May be adding the full implementation to the question would help debugging this discrepancy.